# Convert a ceiling fan controlled by two switches to a remote control

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I would like to convert a ceiling fan with light from 2 switches (one for the light and one for the fan) to a single remote control. Is there a best practice or do I just pick a line and cap off one at the ceiling fan box? Is there anyway to keep both the fan and light on separate switches and have them both remote control as well?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to replace the switch with a remote controlled switch. Since you currently have two outputs, you'd need to find one that has two outputs - I believe they sell one which has a button for the fan and another for the light. Regardless, they'd still have to be separate.

Also, getting this to work would require no modification to the fan itself or the wiring at it. Everything would be changed at the switches.

If you can't find a remote switch module that allows two outputs, then you'd have to leave one currently as is and only control the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy fan remote kits.  The transmitter fits in fan junction box and comes with wireless remote.  You wouldn't have to touch light switches.  There is different brands that work with specific fans.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wanting to use a remote rather than a switch, just hook one of the hot wires coming out of the ceiling to a remote receiver's black wire and hook the white wire from the receiver to a common in the ceiling.  There are 3 wires coming out of the receiver.  These are black, white, and red or blue (color wire).  Hook the white to the white coming from the fan; the black to the black coming from the fan and the color wire to the blue coming from the fan...Cap off the unused hot wire coming from the ceiling making one of the two switches on the wall inoperable.